# Angular's property binding is driving me crazy

Tags: html, angular

I'm new to Angular and I am struggling to bind data from list-articles to another component called Article. I tried for several hours and it does not work.

```
<!--list-articles.component.html-->

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let a of Articles;"><article [Titre]="a.Titre" [Description]="a.Description" [Banniere]="a.Banniere"></article></li>
</ul>
```

```
//list-articles.component.ts
export class ListArticlesComponent {
  Articles:ArticleComponent[] = [{Titre:"article1",Banniere: ".../imgs/images.png", Description:"Voici l'article1"},
  {Titre:"article1",Banniere:".../imgs/images.png", Description:"Voici l'article1"},
  {Titre:"article1",Banniere:".../imgs/images.png", Description:"Voici l'article1"}];
}
```

```
//ArticleComponent.ts
export class ArticleComponent {
  @Input()
  Titre:string ="";
  Banniere:string="";
  Description:string="";
  
}
```

```
<!--article.component.html-->
<div>
    <img />
    <h4>{{Titre}}</h4>
    <p>{{Description}}</p>
</div>
```

I changed the syntax of the properties in list-articles.component.ts a dozen times and it does not display anything (see image below). The expected result should be the data in list-articles.component.ts displayed in the ul. I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

[image]

edit: this should be the result

[image: This should be the result:]

Thank you and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at the ArticleComponent.

```
// ArticleComponent.ts
export class ArticleComponent {
  @Input()
  Titre:string ="";
  Banniere:string="";
  Description:string="";
  
}
```

The `@Input` decorator must be in the same line as the property, and must pre present at every property:

```
// ArticleComponent.ts
export class ArticleComponent {
  @Input() Titre:string ="";
  @Input() Banniere:string="";
  @Input() Description:string="";
}
```

I really suggest you reading the Angular docs starting from the Getting Started:

https://angular.io/guide/what-is-angular

Also as suggested by @joka00 you should not use existing html tags names for components.

Angular suggestions you adding an `app-` prefix to your components to avoid names colisions. That's the default behavior of `ng g component`.

Comment: I would add that the `article` tag can't be used the way it was provided in the example code. That could lead to another errors since [`article` is valid HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article)

Answer (score -1):

You are using `let asdf of Articles` which means, Article's properties should be accessed by `asdf` object but you are trying to access it using `a` object which is wrong.

Correct template would be:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let asdf of Articles;"><article [Titre]="asdf.Titre" [Description]="asdf.Description" [Banniere]="asdf.Banniere"></article></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, there was an error in the code I provided, but even without it, the <li> are still empy.